# WPF Databinding with XMLDataProvider and Namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, namespaces, xmldataprovider

We have a XML File with different Namespaces, you can see it below, and i would like to bind the xml file to the XmlDataProvider. The Namespaces need to be removed, otherwise i cannot load the xml into the data source. Problem:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

This is my XML and the Binding Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.04" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.04 camt.054.001.04.xsd">

<Grid.DataContext>
            <XmlDataProvider x:Name="xdata" XPath="//RmtInf/Strd/CdtrRefInf" >
            </XmlDataProvider>
</Grid.DataContext>
```

The Data Load works fine, and it shows the right Values, but i cannot safe the File, because:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: The 'xmlns' attribute is bound to the reserved namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/'.

This is my code to load the XML:

```
 XmlDocument d = new XmlDocument();
            using (XmlTextReader tr = new XmlTextReader(filePath))
            {
                tr.Namespaces = false;
                d.Load(tr);
            }
            xdata.Document = d;
            xdata.Refresh();
```

Do I need to add the namespaces again? Just a default or a special one?
Thanks for your help and your feedback.

Comment: The error is  occurring because there is not closing tag for </Document>.

Comment: The </document> tag is the last one at the end of my xml. This cannot be the problem